# JS async / await Pokemon Api

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have an async function being called after I click a button called "next". The code is awaiting a fetch from `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`, where the `ID` should update for each time the event listener is clicked. However I can't seem to find a way to change the `id` constant in the `async` function at my current skill level and wondering if there is a better way to write this? For example, I declared `id=1` since the first pokemon is Bulbasaur. Now for every time I click on the event listener called "next", I want the function to refresh by incrementing 1 to the id variable in the function.

```
    async function nextPokemon(){
    let id = 1
    const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`);
    const pokemon = await res.json()
   }

next.addEventListener('click', nextPokemon)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your variable outside the function, here is an example

```js
let id = 1
    async function nextPokemon(){
        const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`);
        const pokemon = await res.json()
        console.log(id)
        id++
       }
 next=document.getElementById("btn")      
next.addEventListener('click', nextPokemon)
```

```html
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so! I also applied that same concept to a function called prevPokemon. I see the "id" variable decrease after putting 'id -- " in the function after I press a new prev.addeventlistener('click', prevPokemon). However the Pokemon that shows does not decrease but fluctuates between current Pokemon's ID and  the next. I am not sure why but still digging...

Comment: I suggest you post a new question regarding the new issue, and leave a link here for me to look into it.

Comment: I did! Thank you for that! I also posted another question after doing some work around..let me know what you think or if anything is unclear :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63063123/javascript-async-and-await-event-listener-pokemon